# What is the best Subversion GUI?

Tags: applications

I'm looking for "the best" SVN GUI/manager for Mac OS, allowing things like line by line comparison, merging, branching, ...

I tried Versions for a few days but now I found that Cornerstone might be a good alternative (better ?).

I was wondering if anyone would have some feedback on these two apps (or on others ...).

Comment: Next time, could you consider rephrasing your question so it does not generate purely subjective feedback ("the best")? Also see the FAQ on this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Asmus has a valid point, but I would even go so far as to point out the "the best" is purely subjective, especially here since some will say Versions and some will say Cornerstone. You will get better responses overall if you list specifically what your needs and wishes are for a GUI SVN app and then you can decide what works for you rather than letting the community decide for you.

Comment: OK, I agree this is far on subjective side. But I was also asking for general feedback, and behavior regarding merging and branching.

Comment: Both Versions and Cornerstone offer 30 day evals. I'd suggest you take complete advantage of those and not make a purchase until 60 days from now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used both, bought Versions in the end. They were both about equal in my use cases. What really helped was adding [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) to my tool box and using it for diffs instead of the XCode diff engine or the simple diff engine in Versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's really subjective, but IMHO it's [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php). In my setup I use:

- Cornerstone
- Kaleidoscope
- svnX
- svn via iTerm2

Answer (score 0):

[svnX](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx)

> SvnX is an open source GUI for most features of the svn client binary. It allows you to browse your working copies, spot changes and operate on them but also to browse logs and revisions of your repositories

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Nice GUI, freeware, multiple function: SourceTree
http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/